# Execute code from a closed workbook without opening it

Tags: excel, vba

The code works if both spreadsheets are open.

The source: MACC_Analysis_Consolidated.xlsx
The destionation: MRP.xlsm

Both are in the same folder.

I need the macro to run without opening the source file "MACC_Analysis_Consolidated.xlsx".

```vb
Sub CopyMRP()
'
' CopyMRP Macro
'

'
    Windows("MACC_Analysis_Consolidated.xlsx").Activate
    Range("I2:I28").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("MRP.xlsm").Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    
    Range("D1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    
End Sub
```

Comment: How are you planning to read what's in it without opening it?

Comment: Put the macro in the PERSONAL worksheet - usually hidden.

Comment: use workbooks.open then use application.screenupdating=false at the start of the code, run code then close the workbook then application.screenupdating=true at the end

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As a closed Excel Workbook cannot be read, so we use an alternative, without open the source data a priori, but open it in the code, then close it after our job, like this:

The macro `CopyMRP()` is defined in a common module in `MRP.xlsm`.

```
Sub CopyMRP()
'
' CopyMRP Macro
'
    Dim wkb As Workbook
    '
    'Windows("MACC_Analysis_Consolidated.xlsx").Activate
    '
    Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\MACC_Analysis_Consolidated.xlsx")
    wkb.Worksheets(1).Range("I2:I28").Copy
    '
    'Selection.Copy
    '
    'wkb.Windows(1).Visible = False
    '
    
    Windows("MRP.xlsm").Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    
    Range("D1").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    
    wkb.Close
    Set wkb = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

The code has been tested working.